# what firewall rules does traceroute need?

Tags: networking, traceroute

The network team told me I only needed ICMP 8 bi directional for traceroute to work but it still does not seem to be working. ping does work with ICMP 8 being open but what do I need to open for traceroute to work?

I get this right now

```
[root]:$ traceroute server1
traceroute to server1 (x.x.x.x), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets
1  * * *
2  * * *
3  * * *
4  * * *
5  * * *
6  * * *
```

Answer (score 1):

In some distributions `Traceroute` use `UDP` you can give it `-I` so it will use `ICMP`, or `-T` for `TCP`.
The reason for it to use UDP in some distributions is because that way it won't need root permission to run.

Comment: Yes port depends on if 32 or 64 or bigger size...

Answer (score 0):

looks like I need this also for regular traceroute 8/ICMP, 33434-33689/UDP, I'm on linux and solaris systems.

I tried the -I and -T options but I don't have root on all systems in production